# Trouble finding syntax error in bash script?

Tags: bash, scripting

The program is meant to create a random number and check if it is lesser than, greater than or equal to the number that the user inputs while the count is less than 3.

```
#!/bin/sh
ranNum=$(($RANDOM % (2 - 1)))
ranNum=$((1 + $ranNum))
c=1

echo "The entity with the greatest number wins"
while [ $c -lt 3 ]
do
    echo "Enter a number"
    read usrIn
    if ["$usrIn" -gt "$ranNum"]
    then
        echo "You won"
        ((c++))
    if ["$usrIn" -lt "$ranNum"]
    then
        echo "You lost"
        ((c++))
    else
        echo "Its a tie"
        ((c++))
        break
    fi
done
```

When I run the code in the shell I get 2 errors returned:

line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
line 24:`done'

I'm not sure what's wrong with the syntax of my code or where to go from here.

Comment: Two `if`s but one `fi` is a good place to start debugging.

Comment: Check out [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net), it's made for this kind of thing

Comment: didn't even think of it, thank you

Comment: In addition to the `if` vs `elif` issue and spacing in the test commands, `$(($RANDOM % (2 - 1)))` will always expand to "0" (because 2-1 is 1, and anything%1 is 0).

Answer (score 3):

The second "if" statement should be "elif"